# ASP.NET vNext DataAnnotations DatabaseGenerated not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm trying define a model ID variable like this in ASP.NET 5:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

To support data annotations I've added the package `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` in my project.json file like this:

```
"System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.0.10-beta-22811"
```

And in the model cs file I've added `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`

Though I get the following error:

> Error CS0433  The type 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' exists in both 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

And I don't know how I should fix this really. I've tried to include the namespace `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` instead of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` but it seems like it doesn't exist as I get this error then:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Annotations' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

And if that namespace does not exist I don't understand how I can get the previous error which tells me that DatabaseGeneratedAttribute exists in two places.

I would really appreciate all help I can get with this.

Comment: First of all, ASP.NET doesn't know what a database is.  So you're not using ASP.NET, neither does MVC.  They are database agnostic.  This means you're using a data access technology like Entity Framework, which has nothing to do with ASP.NET and is unrelated, other than the fact that you might use Entity Framework in an ASP.NET app.  Given that you're using Entity framework, the next question is.. what version?  EF6 or EF7?  And which version of ASP.NET 5 are you using?  There have been 6 CTP releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the KeyAttribute. That should do the auto generation for you.

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

This attribute is available in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace

However, if you want to continue using the DatabaseGeneratedAttribute. The error is pretty self explanatory. It tells you that it is available in both namespaces

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations     
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
```

You will need to explicity state the namespace you need to use E.g.

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

You can always use an **alias** to keep the namespace short and sweet.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your project does not have reference to both version of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll assembly.

Old version (4.0.0.0) can be included to your project by default, and do not be removed after you install package with new version (4.0.10.0).

Comment: Thanks. Got it working though but I still think I've got two versions there. I'm going to check that.